# How to form the .bnd files while using maven-bundle-plugin?

Tags: maven, osgi, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

I'd like to build osgi components and I have been told to use `maven-bundle-plugin`. I started off by adding this into my `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <obrRepository>NONE</obrRepository>
                    <instructions>
                        <_include>-bnd.bnd</_include>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Notice the `.bnd` file which is passed to `<_include>` tag. I've heard people saying that these files should be kept at minimum, or even empty, and then should be observed what imports/exports are needed, etc. This is where I get confused. I have my `MANIFEST.MF` file, in which I know what to import and export. However, I need a bit of help to make my `.bnd` files working. Right now I am trying with empty `.bnd` files and I am not sure if it is working as it should be.

Does anyone have any experience with this plugin and the way I want to make it work?

For instance, [here](https://github.com/evandor/skysail-bundled-libraries/blob/master/skysail.bundles.beanutils/osgi.bnd) is a sample `.bnd` file. However I don't know how he decided that these should imports/exports be there.

As of now, when I try to test the `.jar` I get

```
no main manifest attribute, in bundle-1.0.0.jar
```

error despite of the fact that there is indeed `MANIFEST.MF` in the `.jar`.

**Update:** I thought I could share the `MANIFEST.MF` that I had previously, which I want to generate via this plugin now.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Just a Name
Bundle-SymbolicName: just.a.name.broker;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Require-Bundle: org.apache.activemq,
 just.msg
Bundle-Activator: just.a.broker.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: javax.naming,
 javax.xml,
 javax.xml.parsers,
 org.apache.log4j.xml,
 org.osgi.framework
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Export-Package: just.a.broker
```

So in order to have such a manifest, how should my `.bnd` file look like? Or is it better to include the properties in the plugin rather than passing the `.bnd` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your .bnd file may be look like this:

```
Bundle-Activator: just.a.broker.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.apache.activemq,\
  just.msg 

Import-Package: *,\
  javax.naming,\
  javax.xml,\
  javax.xml.parsers,\
  org.apache.log4j.xml,\
  org.osgi.framework

Bundle-ClassPath: .
Export-Package: just.a.broker
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It definitely did!